# Can't select iOS simulator in Xcode

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6

I updated Xcode to the 6.1 version and now I don't understand why I can't select the simulator in the top left corner like in the previous version when I want to run my application. The only choice that appear is a general "iOS device".

Comment: Did you update from Xcode 6.0 or from 5.x?

Comment: Is this a workspace? If so, make sure your project is pulled in and restart Xcode.

Comment: Restart your computer.

Comment: Anyway, did you check the available downloads? Make sure it actually installed the SDKs and simulators.

Comment: Check you deployment target.

Comment: I updated from 5.x. I restarted the iMac. I checked the available downloads. SDks and simulators are installed. I am so confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the solution. When I added a simulator in the devices menu (Shift+Cmd+2) I got this error: "Unable to determine SimDeviceSet, set_path=/Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices"
I checked the directory and there was not the folder "CoreSimulator", so I created it. I restarted XCode and now there are all the iOS Simulators selectable for running my app.

Thank you all.

Comment: Just re-set the developer dir using `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` (or where ever your developer directory is located).

Comment: I was unable to create a simulator until following this solution. But note that I also had to create the directory with sudo, and then chown it to myself before it would work.

Answer (score 33):

Press "Window" and then "Devices", check if they appear there and if not - click the "+" icon in the lower left

Comment: Worked for me. Somehow an Xcode upgrade (6.0 to 6.1) had removed my simulators, I had to recreate them.

Comment: saved  time, nice solution +1.

Answer (score 29):

Go to **File** -> **Project Settings** -> **Info**.
Change the deployment target to a lower or higher version.

Most probably you do not have a simulator installed for the current deployment target. You can do so by going to **Xcode Preferences** -> **Downloads**. In the Components section, you will see the options for downloading the simulators you already don't have.

Faced the same issue many times and found this solution. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Ok, thank you! The simulator is downloaded but indeed there are no simulator installed when I click shift+cmd+2. I get this error when I try to add one simulator: Unable to determine SimDeviceSet, set_path=/Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices

Comment: You don't need to add simulators. They are automatically installed and detected according to the Deployment Target you use. The organizer window that opens when you press Shift+Cmd+2 is for devices, not simulators.

Comment: Ok, but I still have the problem. The only option for run my project is "iOS Device", there are no iOS simulator to select.

Comment: Did you check the Deployment Target?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that you are having issues communicating with CoreSimualtorService due to renaming Xcode.app or similar.  This is mentioned in the Xcode 6.0 and 6.1 release notes.  Unfortunately, the only workaround at the moment is for you to rename it back or reboot.

**Update**:

Note that for current (as of this update) versions of Xcode (7.2+), renaming should work ok.  For best results, only use one version of Xcode at a time.  If you start another version of Xcode while one is running, the previous one will loose access to simulator devices.  Restarting it will cause it to have access to the simulator devices (and of course the other one to stop).  Basically, the last one wins.

Comment: Happened to me using Xcode 8 (just installed official release, on top of GM), having also (renamed) older version on the same machine that I launch now and then to work on Swift 2.x projects. Restarting Xcode 8 did the trick.

Comment: @NicolasMiari You should be able to work on Swift 2 projects with Xcode 8 still.  It includes Swift 2 as well.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced same issue.My OS is 10.9.5. I solved this issue by downloading IOS simulator 7.1 from Xcode Preferences -> Downloads -> iOS 7.1 Simulator.
And then Windows -> Devices -> added simulator devices by clicking +.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Window -> Devices and Simulators, check whether there is any Simulator listed. If no, add by clicking over "-" over the lower left corner. Or if devices are there but you are not able to see them in devices to be choose from, then check for deployment target that might not be compatible with Xcode simulators, set target according to your Xcode support and you will see the simulators list.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, after delete xcuserdata from my folder, then simulate only have my mac without any other options. after search, I found in scheme setting, Run->Info->Executable without any app. Then I select my app in the project. then simulator all come back.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Xcode
- Open preferences `Command + ,`
- Navigate to `Platforms` tab
- Make sure iOS and iOS simulators are installed.

**Note: Sometimes the issue could be due to invalid cache, so if they were installed before yet you still face the issue, try removing (right click + Delete...) them from the platforms tab then downloading them again.**

Once you are done with the previous steps you should be able to select simulators and create new ones.